# There should be a section for less or inexperienced programmers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think that it would be highly beneficial for users like myself who are less or indeed inexperienced with programming, to have a section where said user could talk to a professional without fear of being insulted or disregarded when there questions aren't clear. I have had first hand experience of not having the correct terminology or indeed not hitting the topic at all because quite frankly I don't know where to start I don't know how to explain my problems. If there was a section for users to be brought up to a certain level of understanding it wouldn't seem so much like this forum is for seasoned professionals :/

Comment: You can suggest an new site on area51. Consider, however, that no experienced programmers would venture to such a place and thus, no good answers will come forth.

Comment: There have been a lot of duplicates of this, just check out the related tab.

Comment: I think you're combining a few different issues here.  The point of SO is not to be a friendly environment for discussing code; it's to post questions and answer them.  So in that sense, this would be very much against the point of SO.  The lack of friendliness, on the other hand, is quite relevant, but shouldn't be linked to experience or anything else.

Comment: yes there are many duplicates and they all have multiple downvotes its quite annoying

Comment: Tells you that the suggestion is thought as a bad one by the people here...

Comment: All a newbie needs to do is to read http://tinyurl-com/so-hints, and follow the instructions there, and their question will succeed.  Sadly, most will not.  Maybe they should try [asking the duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) first.

Comment: I don't see why its perfectly valid instead of just disregarding them as bad questions do people on here not want to help people improve instead of having question after question closed then people like me getting no where nearer to finishing vital tasks that I need to complete?

Comment: We're here to help people with their programming problems, not their communications skills.  That may seem blunt, but it's just the way it is.  As Stack Overflow has gotten more popular, it has attracted more and more people who have not done the necessary work to become reasonably competent first.  If we were to focus on helping them get better at communicating, we would no longer be helping people with their programming problems; we'd be spending all our time helping people communicate better.

Comment: Your vital tasks are vital to you, not to us.

Comment: communication isn't the problem what about people that don't understand what they have been told?

Comment: @joran I know that but what if you had something that you could not understand and asked for help and just got thrown aside?

Comment: Pick yourself up, dust yourself off and put in some effort to solve your problems @NathanTaylor....that should be the response.

Comment: its not that easy when you don't even know what to search for have you every tried searching for something that is like speaking a different language??

Comment: I never claimed it was easy.

Comment: im sorry that I appear to be aggressive but I just don't like the 'get good' attitude that some people have on here it just demoralises people that are already stressed to hell trying to understand something new...

Comment: If your task is that pressing, maybe making a big fuss on Meta isn't the best use of your time...?

Comment: im doing research at the same time

Comment: "Your vital tasks are vital to you, not to us." How is possible so selfish comment to have 3 upvotes. It's seems that gaining rank is the vital for someone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a self described "newbie", I kind of like the idea of a place where one could ask the "stupid" questions we often have but there are a few problems I can think of:

**1: How will you keep it from becoming "give me teh codez"?**

Many new comers just want the answer so they can move on with life. A place for new programmers will have a very high concentration of these questions. If the answer is "these questions will be closed" (as they should be), that leads into my next question....

**2: What will be different about this "NewbieOverFlow"?**

What differentiates NO from SO other than "that's where newbies go"?  Will the privileges needed going to require less rep? How will you deal with the increase in spam? Will experts still visit? I'm willing to bet some would, but a good portion will prefer to avoid the boring repeated question and stay in SO. What makes a good NO question? Are you still going to require research or can everyone ask "How do I declare a variable in java"? If the same posting guidelines exist, then....

**3: Why not just post on StackOverFlow?**

I agree that SO tends to be rather unforgiving to new comers. Its for the best but it still sucks to get downvotes. However, if you have a good questions for NO, wouldn't that likely be a good question for SO? Forcing people to do their homework makes a better community and better programmers out of those that learn the right way to post.

Comment: +1, which I could +more ... thanks for taking the time to write. As perhaps stated in the comments above, the best place to spend effort should be on improving the communication between newbies and experienced SO people (i.e. flagging inappropriately snarky comments, etc.)

Comment: Let's be honest, there is a place for the kind of questions the OP is referring to: forums. And we kinda know why many of us are on SO instead.

Comment: Stupid questions? see that's exactly what some people are like on here unforgiving is an understatement people are made to feel stupid even though it takes years to understand one type of programming and their are over 4 different types that I know of as an IT Technician I am fully aware of the temptation to be condescending but on here people seem to go overboard and its counterproductive I see it as kicking people while they are down. have you tried teaching ITQ (word Exel and Powerpoint)to elderly people that are scared of computers? its no different on here if you ask me

Comment: @NathanTaylor Unfortunately the bar is higher on these sites and the range of acceptable questions is different. Rudeness or insults are not acceptable however. Feel free to flag those. But to maintain a level of quality we can't simply accept all questions. And creating a site as you propose, while perhaps helpful to some, will throw quality overboard and introduce all sorts of issues. Learn how to ask good questions. And if you can't, go to one of the many sites which will accept the questions you propose. SO/SE is not the only possibility out there.

Comment: @NathanTaylor ok first, please use periods -> . its difficult to read your run-on sentences. Second, I'm not trying to be condescending, I'm agreeing with you: I'd like a place like that. However, I'm also pointing out that I don't know how this could be done while still keeping the same SO quality.

Comment: so its clear that this site is for people who have a greater understanding of programming then?

Comment: It's not a site that will teach you how to program @NathanTaylor.

Comment: @NathanTaylor well in a sense, yeah. You have to understand, SO is not for answering peoples' questions. I use it for that, obviously :P but its designed to be an online repository of knowledge. You can think of it as a replacement for a book (its an example, roll with it). The whole point is to educate the people who come after you so they don't have to ask. That way, there's less clutter and a better noise-to-signal ratio. Side bonus: this method encourages research and self-reliance, which are both very important for programmers

Comment: @Daniel fair enough at least there are reasonable people on here that understand that its difficult at first

Comment: @NathanTaylor been there, done that, got the T-Shirt. Just take it slow and blend with how it works here and you'll be doing great in no time flat :)