# SO the Most Loved and Hated Website

Tags: discussion

Loved because:

- It's priceless source of programming materials
- It's the place where the brightest programmers are discussing interesting problems
- It's the place where you can (eventually) receive an answer and advices

Hated because:

- The most interesting questions are closed as not constructive. (see the highest voted)
- It's not designed for discussion. (What if you see a very similar question and you want to ask for something or to expand.... You have to open new question instead.)
- If you do not understand completely the subject of your question or the answers, you are downvoted and eventually question closed.

I'm programming from 27 years and really the SO is the only programming oriented website giving me strong negative emotions. How is possible the most popular website to be soo unfriendly.

EDIT: 
 My recommendations are deleted because they have expressed my personal feeling about SO. Of course it's not written especially for me and no one has to be filling obligated to make it such.

My concerns are that probably other users (I mean rank < 1k) may also find it somewhat unfriendly. However the owners of SO has the full rights to maintain it as they want.

N.B
As this is not a real question and it is highly subjective, please moderators to consider deleting this topic.

Comment: Maybe try to stop making it something it's not?

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* an unfriendly website.  The Summer of Love and the new closing system saw to that.  Stack Overflow is, however, considered unfriendly by those who are denied the ability to co-opt it for their own purposes.

Comment: Are really nobody agrees with me? Probably I'm totally lost. But it is about SO. Surprised that the topic is not closed yet.

Comment: **Why**? Why does it have to be everything to everybody? There is an *entire Internet* out there for people who want discussion. Stack Overflow has a purpose, and open-ended discussion is *not it*.

Comment: Well we closed it now, but only because this isn't a question, but a rant.

Comment: Why should SO be responsible for maintaining discussions it was specifically **not** meant to cater to.

Comment: I agree whit all of you. Please vote for deleting this post. It seems it's absolutely inappropriate for this website. Sorry for your lost time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1: chat if you really need to but there a millions of other sites online where you can discuss such points. Why fight to put it here when it'll be welcomed there?

2: Just because a question is downvoted doesn't mean it can't provide useful information. [Here's a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly). This is the most unnecessary of the 3 as the question will still provide useful info or folded into the first category.

3: [I'd like to think I did a decent job answering this idea here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188997/there-should-be-a-section-for-less-or-inexperienced-programmers/189007#189007). Summery: any differentiating factor that makes it more welcoming to newbies will make it less useful to them.

Comment: "Why fight to put it here when it'll be welcomed there?" I'm reading SO for many years. I just like it better (it's highly subjective of course)

Comment: @MiroslavPopov I see where you're coming from but as Robert said, making it something its not in an attempt to be more flexible will end up making it less useful

Comment: Probably you are right. (I'll +1 your comment when I can)

Answer (score 22):

Why do you suppose the first three bullets are true?  Could it be because the second three bullets are true?

Consider the last time you tried to ask a forum for help.  Did you get a meaningful, timely answer to your problem, free of the noise and clutter of random users' posts?  Why not?  Is it because people can do whatever they wish in forum environments?

Stack Overflow is what it is because it doesn't seek to be all things to all people.  Instead, it chooses to adopt a laser-like focus on its primary mission, which is to be a repository for useful programming knowledge.  Anything that does not contribute to that primary mission is discouraged.  Anything that actively detracts from that mission is eliminated.

That's why you love Stack Overflow.

Comment: My +1 for your first paragraph alone. Sometimes I would like this to be displayed in Arial Bold 36pt in a huge banner on every page of every SE site. Then I wake up.